# How to develop 2 level step progress bar in HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

I am trying to develop a two level step progress bar using html & css and I am facing a lot of challenges..

Here is the code I have tried so far

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #8C9EFF;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.card {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.top {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 13% !important;
  padding-right: 13% !important;
}


/*Icon progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #455A64;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 7%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#progressbar .step0:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f10c";
  color: #fff;
}

#progressbar .step0:before {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 52px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#progressbar .step1:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f10c";
  color: #fff;
}

#progressbar .step1:before {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 28px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}


/*ProgressBar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}

#progressbar li:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

#progressbar li:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}


/*Color number of the step and the connector before it*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  /* background: grey; */
}

#progressbar .step0:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  /* content: "\f00c"; */
}

#progressbar li.step1:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  /* content: "\f00c"; */
}

.icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.icon-content {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .icon-content {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

#progressbar .spec:before {
  background-color: green !important;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

#progressbar .high:before {
  background-color: green !important;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

#progressbar .mid:before {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

#progressbar .low:before {
  background-color: red !important;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

#progressbar .spec:after {
  background-color: green !important;
}

#progressbar .high:after {
  background-color: green !important;
}

#progressbar .mid:after {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

#progressbar .low:after {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid px-1 px-md-4 py-5 mx-auto">
  <div class="card mb-5">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between px-3 top"></div>
    
    <!-- Add class 'active' to progress -->
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <ul id="progressbar" class="text-center">

          <li class="active step0 spec" id="a">
            <p class="font-weight-bold mt-3 node">a</p>
          </li>

          <li class="active step1 clickable" id="b">
            <p class="font-weight-bold mt-3 node ">b
            </p>
          </li>

          <li class="active step1 clickable" id="c">
            <p class="font-weight-bold mt-3 node">c
            </p>
          </li>


          <li class="active step0" id="d">
            <p class="font-weight-bold mt-3 node">d</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to position 'b' under 'c' as shown in the below.

This code outputs the following image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9QlZ.png)

This is the result I am after:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uySE.png)

Thank you friends.

Comment: position: absolute might work, though I would imagine you would have to rework a lot of your pseudo elements

Answer (score 0):

There's a so many way to resolve it.
But best easy way is add some margin top.

```
#progressbar .step1:before {      
  margin-top: 17px; /* add css  */
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #8C9EFF;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.card {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.top {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 13% !important;
  padding-right: 13% !important;
}


/*Icon progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #455A64;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 7%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#progressbar .step0:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f10c";
  color: #fff;
}

#progressbar .step0:before {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 52px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#progressbar .step1:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f10c";
  color: #fff;
}

#progressbar .step1:before {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 28px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 17px; /* add css  */
}


/*ProgressBar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}

#progressbar li:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

#progressbar li:last-child:after {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}


/*Color number of the step and the connector before it*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  /* background: grey; */
}

#progressbar .step0:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  /* content: "\f00c"; */
}

#progressbar li.step1:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  /* content: "\f00c"; */
}

.icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.icon-content {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .icon-content {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

#progressbar .spec:before {
  background-color: green !important;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

#progressbar .high:before {
  background-color: green !important;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

#progressbar .mid:before {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

#progressbar .low:before {
  background-color: red !important;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

#progressbar .spec:after {
  background-color: green !important;
}

#progressbar .high:after {
  background-color: green !important;
}

#progressbar .mid:after {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

#progressbar .low:after {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid px-1 px-md-4 py-5 mx-auto">
  <div class="card mb-5">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between px-3 top"></div>
    
    <!-- Add class 'active' to progress -->
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <ul id="progressbar" class="text-center">

          <li class="active step0 spec" id="a">
            <p class="font-weight-bold mt-3 node">a</p>
          </li>

          <li class="active step1 clickable" id="b">
            <p class="font-weight-bold mt-3 node ">b
            </p>
          </li>

          <li class="active step1 clickable" id="c">
            <p class="font-weight-bold mt-3 node">c
            </p>
          </li>


          <li class="active step0" id="d">
            <p class="font-weight-bold mt-3 node">d</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```